# python: run java command using variables in the command

Tags: java, python, bash

I have a large python script and parses data and then preps it for import to another system. I want to trigger the import to the other system from this script as well.

the bash script to import looks something like this

```
export DPATH="/home/user/"
export DCONF="/home/user/conf"
java -cp "$DPATH/*" -D.config.dir=$DCONF com.sa.uploader.process.ProcessRunner process.name=upsert
```

In my python script I want to do something like this:

```
dpath = "/home/user/"
dconf = "/home/user/conf"
drun  = " -cp "+str(dpath)+" -D.config.dir="+str(dconf)+" com.sa.uploader.process.ProcessRunner process.name=upsert"
```

that way I can simply run this:

```
java = subprocess.call(['java', drun])
```

Obviously, the drun portion of the last line there isn;t recognized as a valid thing to run. The error is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class  -cp .home.user.....etc
```

I then test this:

```
java = subprocess.call(['java', '-version'])
```

Which does work. So i then tried:

```
jtest = " -version"

java = subprocess.call(['java', jtest])
```

and of course.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class  -version
```

I'm sure theres a way to do this. 
The reason is because the java command will be the same every time, but the paths can change. Ill eventually make the path varabiales args to they can be inputs. For now I just want it to work statically.

Comment: For the java version command just remove the spaces.. It should be subprocess.call(['java','-version']). Similarly do edits for the above commands.

Comment: How does `subprocess.call['java', -version])` possibly work? Did you mean `subprocess.call['java', '-version'])`?

Comment: yes, I meant subprocess.call['java', '-version']) -works

the issue is that when I put -version into a variable called jtest,I'd like to be able to use the variable instead of the '-version'   i.e. (jtest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either split the command line into a list or use shell e.g.

```
subprocess.call(['java'] + drun.split())
```

or

```
subprocess.call('java' + drun, shell=True)
```

Comment: thanks! this did it.     java = subprocess.call(['java' + jtest], shell=True) looks like the + was what I was looking for. What does the shell=True  do? I'll google it as well but if its a simple answer.   Thanks again!

Comment: _subprocess.call()_ passes the parameter list as is to operating system _exec()_ which expects a string array.

_shell=True_ - as the name suggest - wraps the command in a shell before calling _exec()_. See https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py#l1443

Comment: will this also work if I set shell=False like subprocess.call('java' + cmd, shell=False)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class you are trying to run isn't in the path specified by the `dpath`. In your shell script you have:

```
java -cp "$DPATH/*"
```

Notice the asterisk after the forward slash. But in your python you don't have it, you can change the python to:

```
dpath = "/home/user/*"
```

This will cause the `-cp` to expand to a list of all the `jar` files you have in that directory.
You can read more about the `-cp` option [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That would probably have been an issue on the NEXT step for me. so thanks.

For this issue, I've tried to simplify it with my java -version test

so taking away all the other variables, if I just want to run this in the script:

    java -version 

but instead of having to type -version out I want to put -version into a variable called jtest

now how do I run java with the variable jtest and still get the results of what java -version would do if written out